# Как сделать цикл со временем в виде переменных?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно сделать цикл который выводит список времен в зависимости от заданного периода времени. Условно есть начальное `i = 10:30`, дальше идет условие ,например, `i<=14:30` и заданный период `i+=1:00`. В таком случае вывод бы был [10:30 11:30 12:30 13:30 14:30].
Вот моя несчастная попытка реализации... **`for (i = new Date("10:00"); i<=new Date("20:30"); i = new Date(+i + period * 6e4))`**. Заранее спасибо за данные ответы и предложения!

Answer (score 0):

Вообще можно не придумывать велосипед и воспользоваться set interval https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval

Если вам нужно чтобы итерация проходила час, то можно сделать так

```
while(isDateLowerThan(yourDate){
  setTimeout...{
    alert(Date.now())
  }
}
```

Comment: Извините, думаю вы что то не так поняли. Мне просто нужно получить массив времен. В виде времен или чисел.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел на просторах интернета:

```
 var start_time = new Date();
 start_time.setHours(10,30,0);//10:30
 var end_time = new Date();
 end_time.setHours(18,30,0);//18:30
```